# Is it possible that an update is delayed for a very long time in React18 with concurrent rendering?

Tags: reactjs, concurrency, deferred-rendering, react-concurrent

As I know, in React 18, a concurrent task can interrupted by an urgent update.
So, is it possible that a concurrent task is delayed for a very long time or may never be executed because there is always an urgent update is executed?

If not, then why? Can you explain?

Comment: If you have so many urgent updates that you never have time to do anything else, your code is probably broken to begin with. The question makes no sense.

Comment: Can you help to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it sounds there is something very wrong with your concurrent rendering method